# How to iterate over the third array dimension returning a the 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

i have got a 3d numpy array, what is the best way to iterate over the third dimension in a for loop returning the 2d array of the current interation?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Please show a code snippet that demonstrates your question.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be just by iterating with range from 0 to the length of the array:

```
# arr = 3d numpy array
for i in range(len(arr)):
    print(arr[i])
```

Comment: This iterates on the first dimension of the array.

Answer (score 0):

just loop with its third dim:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(24).reshape((2,3,4))
for i in range(a.shape[2]):         # index 2 is for 3rd dimension
    print(a[:, :, i])
    # or
    print(a[..., i])
```

then you got it.

but using loop with numpy array is costly, you should [get used](https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/) to broadcasting, vectorization, indexing...